# snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 001003 (42000) when inserting DataFrame to Snowflake

Tags: python, pandas, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

OK, here is the Snowflake docs how to bring a pandas DataFrame to Snowflke:
[https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-api.html#label-python-connector-api-write-pandas][1]

I'm trying to follow exact instructions. My dataframe is here:

```
df_t = pd.DataFrame([(1.9204, 0, 1, 46.7300, 0, 113000, 113000, '2012-03-10 13:09:06.290',
                     '2012-03-10 13:09:06.290',  50192, 'A', 'Y', 'N', 'N', 'NNN', 2, 0, 1,
                     '2012-03-10 19:50:58.233', '2012-03-10 19:50:59.800', '2020-02-27 15:10:07.457',
                     '2020-02-27 15:10:07.457',168)], columns = cols)
```

Actually, I'm trying to bring data from SQL Server->DataFrame->Snowflake. Please, don't tell me about csv files. I did it already. :-)

Anyway, after using this, according to docs, I execute a function:

```
success, nchunks, nrows, _ = write_pandas(conn, df_t, 'Some_Table')
```

And I get this error:

```
snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 001003 (42000): SQL compilation error:
 syntax error line 1 at position 87 unexpected '~'.
 parse error line 1 at position 98 near '76'.
 parse error line 1 at position 104 near '84'.
 parse error line 1 at position 109 near '116'.
 parse error line 1 at position 121 near '102'.
 syntax error line 1 at position 126 unexpected '.'.
 syntax error line 1 at position 131 unexpected '@"swjrp"'
```

Some posts (lost the link) said that it's a connector problem, but it was going to be fixed in version 1.23. So, it's version 3, I believe. Is that a bug or my curly brains?

Comment: Could you provide the DDL of the table you are trying to write into on Snowflake?  Also, the connectors have a GitHub location that you can report issues on here:  https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-python/issues